# Trying to invoke method in unity. Method cannot be called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, invoke

```
void Update()
{
    if (currentTarget != null)
    {
        this.Invoke("Shoot(currentTarget)", 0.3f);
    }
}

void Shoot(Collider currentTarget)
{
    .......
}
```

I want the Shoot method to be called fast. But all I get is

```
Trying to Invoke method: Tower.Shoot(currentTarget) couldn't be called.
```

What can be the problem ?

Comment: What language? C# or Javascript? Where is the shoot function? In another class or the same class?

Comment: C#, in the same class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **cannot** call Invoke **with** **parameters**. This should work if you **remove** the parameter from your Shoot function.

```
Invoke("Shoot", 3f);
```

Then your shoot function should look like this

```
void Shoot(){
}
```

instead of

```
void Shoot(string...parameter){
}
```

After your comment, there is another way to do this. That requires "**Coroutine**".

```
 IEnumerator Shoot(Collider currentTarget, float delayTime)
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);
         //You can then put your code below
       //......your code
     }
```

You cannot call it directly. For example, you cannot do this:
`Shoot(currentTarget, 1f)`;

You must use `**StartCoroutine**(Shoot(currentTarget, 1f));`

```
 void Start()
 {
    //Call your function
     StartCoroutine(Shoot(currentTarget, 1f));
 }
```

Also if you dont like using **StartCoroutine**, then you can call the Coroutine function inside another normal function. I think you may like this method so the whole code should look like something below:

```
 //Changed the name to **ShootIEnum**
 IEnumerator ShootIEnum(Collider currentTarget, float delayTime=0f)
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);
         //You can then put your code below
       //......your code
     }

//You call this function 
void Shoot(Collider currentTarget, float delayTime=0f)
{
 StartCoroutine(ShootIEnum(currentTarget, 1f));
}

void Update()
    {
        if (currentTarget != null)
        {
           Shoot(currentTarget,  0.3f);
        }
    }
```

Now, anytime you want to call Shoot, you can now call `Shoot(currentTarget, 1f);`  with no problems.

Comment: But what if I must call Shoot with parameters? Any other way instead of using Invoke ?

Comment: Yes there is. I just updated it. I showed how to call this in from Start function. You cannot call it directly. You must use  "StartCoroutine".    StartCoroutine(Shoot(currentTarget, 1f));

Comment: I think this gives wrong effect anyway. 
In my code during update I check if target is alive, and then shoot. But problem is that it starts shooting continuosly. I think I have some problem with logic. What u think ?

Comment: The solution I posted should solve your the initial problem you were having. There is no where in this code that you are checking if something is alive. You may want to create a new post about what you are trying to do. To me, this is suppose to be shooting if currentTarget  is NOT null and it is doing exactly that. I suggest you create a new post, describe what you are trying to do and post the current code you have and I might help if it is not complicated. If this solved your "Trying to Invoke method: Tower.Shoot(currentTarget) couldn't be called." error, please accept the answer.

Comment: Ok you are right. going to create diferenet post. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and will attempt to help if I can,